# Why django timesince is not working?

Tags: django, locale

I am trying to use timesince from django but I want it shows "semana" instead of "week", as far as I knew we just need to set 2 things in settings and it should work

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.USE_I18N
True
>>> settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
'pt-br'
>>> timesince(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7))
u'1 week'
```

What is wrong here?

More information: I am on Ubuntu 16 and I have a Mac where the code works

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, see if there is any difference

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('pt-br')
print timesince(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7))
```